# Ruby/Sinatra/Datamapper - Iterate through (and puts content of property) of datamapper collection

Tags: ruby, loops, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

https://github.com/emilysas/Chitter

I'm using DataMapper to make a mock of twitter.

I have a model called Peep (Tweet). And I want to be able to show all the tweets via an erb.

If I use

```
<%= Peep.first.content if Peep.first %>
```

Then I get the content I want, but obviously only for one item in my database.

If I try either:

```
<%= Peep.all.content if Peep.first %>
```

Or

```
<%= Peep.all.each {|peep| peep.content} %>
```

I get nothing.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<% Peep.all.each do |peep| %>
<%= peep.content %>
<% end %>
```

To display content you shoud print each item, not the block.